# Wind in video game project

Tags: physics

How to make the wind blow with randomized patterns? Like for storms and calm breezes?

Comment: How are you handling your physics so far? Are you in 2D or 3D? What does your wind need to do? What pseudorandom/noise techniques have you tried so far?

Comment: What's your technology stack? In what way is the wind supposed to affect gameplay? How accurately do you need the simulation to be? Do you need help with visualizing the wind patterns? I'm sorry, but this question does not contain nearily enough information to write any useful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is quite broad, but I think I can point you in the right direction. You have two approaches each with its pros and cons.

1.) Simulate real physics

Pros: the most close to reality.

Cons: computationally expensive, hard  to program.

2.) Use noise

Pros: faster to implement and runs fast also.

Cons: not so close to reality

If you go with the first one you have to implement 3/2 dimensional Computational Fluid Dynamics CFD, I would go with a shader approach. [GPU Gems](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/books/HTML/gpugems/gpugems_ch38.html) is an excellent source.
If you go for the second option I recommend [Curl Noise](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~rbridson/docs/brentw_msc.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjKqPnXo-zhAhVJrVkKHd8NBJkQFjAAegQIBRAB&usg=AOvVaw3hFDq-a_X-vH4TkVLILImm) for nice swirly patterns. I think that you better implement either of the approaches on the GPU for performance.